# Access parent from child in Realm for Android

Tags: android, sqlite, orm, many-to-many, realm

I am creating a chat application using Realm 1.2.0 for Android.

Here are two minimized models I created:

```
public class Room extends RealmObject {

    private String name;

    private RealmList<Message> messages;

}

public class Message extends RealmObject {

    @PrimaryKey
    private long id;

    private String text;

}
```

Using these models, I can get all messages in a specific room. The problem is, I also want to access the room from a message.

For example, this would be possible (accessing the childs from the parent):

```
room.getMessages()
```

But I also want to access the parent from the child, like this:

```
message.getRoom()
```

Is this possible in Realm without manually querying all the rooms again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The concept is called [`backlink`](https://github.com/realm/realm-java/pull/2881), and they're not in yet. In fact, they're in design stage or so, so it'll take a while before automatic inverse relationships are available.

So currently you'd need to maintain both sides of the relationship yourself.

```
public class Room extends RealmObject {

    private String name;

    private RealmList<Message> messages;

}

public class Message extends RealmObject {

    @PrimaryKey
    private long id;

    private String text;

    private Room room;
}
```

---

```
r.executeTransaction((realm) -> {
  Room room = realm.where(Room.class).equalTo("name", name).findFirst();
  Message message = new Message();
  message.setId(getNextId());
  message.setText(text);
  message.setRoom(room);
  message = realm.copyToRealmOrUpdate(message);
  room.getMessages().add(room);
}
```

Comment: Well, that's unfortunate. But thanks for the temporary solution!